# Serve mbtiles without predefined configuration

Tags: vector-tiles, mbtiles, tileserver-gl

I searching for a tileserver, what is capable to serve mbtiles only by giving path to reach the tileset.
Right now i use FME to generate mbtiles from various type of data, and i use Tileserver Gl Light to serve the static tilesets.
The user uploads the data, FME transforms it, and i have to visualise it right after, so i cannot restart the Tileserver for configuration changes.
I found Martin(maplibre) promising, but i cannot decide, it is capable for this. Any experience about it? Any other "light" and easy solution? I would be happy for some example.